# Can't see simple geometry in the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

Apologies - as this may be quite an easy solve. I have the following code, however can't seem to see the `BoxGeometry` in the scene. The red scene shows up fine

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(0, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
var color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);

scene.background = color;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
        {
            color: 0x00ff00
        }
    )
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

The only errors in my console are "THREE.WebGLRenderer 79" and "DevTools failed to parse SourceMap"

Answer (score 1):

So turns out the PerspectiveCamera first variable needs to be e.g. 75 and not 0.